# How could I draw 4 mosfets in a same line? (attached picture)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, circuitikz, circuits

[image]

I only know how to do one and in a unique line. How is it possible to put four together and well spaced as the picture I am showing?

what I did until now:

```
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) node[ nmos ] {};
    \end{circuitikz}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
These are the symbols for mosfets:

\medskip
\begin{circuitikz} 
    \draw (0,0) node[ nmos ] {};
    \draw (4,0) node[ pmos ] {};
    \ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
    \draw (2,0) node[ pmos ] {};
    \draw (6,0) node[ pmos ] {};
    
    \node [align=center] at (1,-1) {nmos};
    \node [align=center] at (5,-1) {pmos};
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Peter grill, a few seconds after you a upload almost the same answer ... Since two equal answer doesn't make a sense, I delete mine.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much. The examples I've found in the web  were only big circuits, which caused lots of problems trying to adjust.

Comment: @FranciscoMaerle: If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I didn't know that. I just accepted. Thanks.